# Rails - using 'create' for different types of models in same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Here is my use case, in bullet points so its nice and easy to follow:

- Admin user is seeded in, of type User and given an "admin" role.
- That Admin user can sign up new students and also new teachers, both are models.
- Admin user goes to new user sign up page (I am using the `Devise` gem template mainly.)
- Selects which type the new user will be with a radio box, either Student or Teacher.
- Upon `Submit`, of course it is the `Users` controller being used here, because Admin is of type User.
- But here, I do not want to use the Users controller `create` method. I want to `create` a new Student or Teacher model. They both have their own controllers, with their own `create` methods, but how do I call them from the User controller? Or, if that is bad practice, I guess more generally my question is how do I create one of these new models instead of the User model?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the real problem here that you in fact should be creating a new user for each new student or admin?

Comment: You're using devise to create user and students and teachers? Can devise be set up that way? Wouldn't you have a separate form?

Comment: DO you have 3 models, User, Teacher, Student?

Comment: Can you post some of the code for the models and the form?

Comment: @JD I just meant that I cut and pasted the devise templates into new forms for each of these models. I had to just change a thing or two in the form_for method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you can check your params for type of new user from your radio box, and then simply call some private method and pass params into, that will create new resource depending on params.

For example

Assume you have in your params key with name of `entity`. You do post on `create#users`

```
def create
  if create_new_resource(params)
    redirect_to some_path
   else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def create_new_resource(params)
   "#{params[:entity].create(params)}" 
end
```

Just for as a start version. You have to do some changes aswell

Comment: Ok nice this looks like basically what I am after. Thanks!